# Javascript return value only gets returned once in loop

Tags: javascript

I created this function to calculated distances I want to measure:

```
distanceToResponder: function() {
    var distance = 0;
    var incidentLocation = this.createCoordinate(this.currentIncident["latitude"], this.currentIncident["longitude"]);

    this.responders.forEach(function(responder) {
        var responderLocation = this.createCoordinate(responder.location.latitude, responder.location.longitude);
        distance = this.calculateDistanceBetweenLocations(incidentLocation, responderLocation);
    }.bind(this));
    return distance;
}
```

for some reason which I do not see, the value for distance is only returned once. So if I throw 2 locations into the forEach function, and I use console.log within the loop, I see everything is calculated correctly. But if I return the value for distance, only one value is returned.

How do I return the value correctly?

I am using VueJS where 'distanceToResponder' is a computed property to fill a table:

```
   <tr v-for="responder in responders">
        <td>{{ responder.userReference }}</td>
        <td>{{ distanceToResponder(responder) }}</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="createDispatch(responder)">Alarm</button></td>
    </tr>
```

so the function should return the distance for each responder. How do I need to adjust my function then?

Comment: You are returning the last calculated `distance`, and you can return from a function just once, anyway. You may be interested in the `Array.map` method

Comment: Well, a function can only return a single value. `return distance;` will return whatever the value of `distance` is at that moment. All you are doing is overwriting the value inside `forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating your responders and each time overwrite distance. Then after iteration returning the distance to the last responder.

```
    var distances = this.responders.map(function(responder) {
      var responderLocation = this.createCoordinate(responder.location.latitude, responder.location.longitude);
      return this.calculateDistanceBetweenLocations(incidentLocation, responderLocation);
    }.bind(this));
    return distances;
```

Make a computed property "distancesToResponders" from this. And in the template

```
 <tr v-for="(index, responder) in responders">
    <td>{{ responder.userReference }}</td>
    <td>{{ distancesToResponder[index] }}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="createDispatch(responder)">Alarm</button></td>
</tr>
```

Or create a "augmented" responders computed property:

```
 respondersWithDistance: function() {

  var incidentLocation = this.createCoordinate(this.currentIncident["latitude"], this.currentIncident["longitude"]);

  return this.responders.map(function(responder) {
    var responderLocation = this.createCoordinate(responder.location.latitude, responder.location.longitude);
    responder.distance = this.calculateDistanceBetweenLocations(incidentLocation, responderLocation);
 }.bind(this));
}
```

And use that also in the template:

```
 <tr v-for="responder in respondersWithDistance">
    <td>{{ responder.userReference }}</td>
    <td>{{ responder.distance }}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="createDispatch(responder)">Alarm</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I want to do the first. but instead of returning an array of distances, I want to fill a table with the individual distances (adjusted questions above) via VueJS

Comment: What would be the "cleaner" or more common way?

Answer (score 2):

You're not using return values at all here, except out of the outer most function call. Your inner `forEach` callback just sets the state of a single variable (`distance`) shared across both functions, which is eventually returned.

Each iteration of `forEach` overwrites the previous value of `distance` so that only the final value is left.

It's unclear what you mean by "return multiple" as a function may return only one value, but you can return an *array* of distances by using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `forEach`:

```
distanceToResponder: function() {
    var incidentLocation = this.createCoordinate(this.currentIncident["latitude"], this.currentIncident["longitude"]);

    return this.responders.map(function(responder) {
        var responderLocation = this.createCoordinate(responder.location.latitude, responder.location.longitude);
        return this.calculateDistanceBetweenLocations(incidentLocation, responderLocation);
    }.bind(this));

}
```

Comment: I edited my question accordingly. Actually I have an array of responders. with VueJS I go through this variable and want to calculate the distance to each individual responder via this function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you want to return an array of distances, one for each responder. As it is, you're overwriting the `distance` variable each time, and only returning its final value. I recommend using `map()` instead of `forEach()` to return all the values as an array:

```
distanceToResponder: function() {
    var incidentLocation = this.createCoordinate(this.currentIncident["latitude"], this.currentIncident["longitude"]);

    return this.responders.map(function(responder) {
        var responderLocation = this.createCoordinate(responder.location.latitude, responder.location.longitude);
        return this.calculateDistanceBetweenLocations(incidentLocation, responderLocation);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The respective responder must be passed as argument. The iteration is done by vue.

```
distanceToResponder: function(responder) {
  var distance = 0;
  var incidentLocation = this.createCoordinate(this.currentIncident["latitude"], this.currentIncident["longitude"]);

  var responderLocation = this.createCoordinate(responder.location.latitude, responder.location.longitude);
  return this.calculateDistanceBetweenLocations(incidentLocation, responderLocation);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping this would work, but distanceToResponder is a computed property and I guess this cannot take an argument? or am I wrong